# Accessing an element in struct holding a pointer to a matrix array

Tags: c

I am trying to access an element using `temp_param->mat_ptr[0][0]` but it produces an error `Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'`. What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int matrix[4][4];

matrix mat;

typedef struct tnode {
    matrix *mat_ptr;
} params;

params temp_param;

int main() {
    temp_param.mat_ptr = &mat;
    /* temp_param->mat_ptr[0][0] produces an error "Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'" */
    printf("%d", temp_param->mat_ptr[0][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of expression `params.mat_ptr` is a pointer to 2D array. Therefore is must be dereferenced before being accessed like 2D array.
Moreover `temp_param` is a struct, not a pointer to struct. Therefore its members are accessed via `.` operator rather than `->`.

Try `(*temp_param.mat_ptr)[0][0]`